What can gingerbread be stored in to both facilitate freshness and absorbing moisture from the air?
In Adam Ragusea's gingerbread video, he specifies that gingerbread is easier to slice a day or two later after the hygroscopic syrups have absorbed water from the air:
https://youtu.be/gq9rFDpIHv0?si=FtXUgeGkFbefFBR2&t=306
What is gingerbread best stored in to maintain freshness and facilitate that effect of "hygroscopic syrups absorbing water from the air"?

I've seen advice to put a cut apple in with some cookies that need to soften.  This would allow you to have a closed container but have moisture for the cookies to absorb.  Some other Pfeffernusse recipes call for making them a month before you plan to eat them so they can soften (they usually mention keeping them "in a tin" which might leak more air than today's plastic containers)

First, if you got your gingerbread relatively recently, no such treatment should be needed. If on the other hand you made for example a gingerbread house, kept it around for a month (indoor but in the open) and now plan to eat it, it will be rock hard and completely dried out so some softening is needed.
I've used storage in a tin box together with a chunk of apple very successfully. A day or two in the box will render the gingerbread moist, easy to cut, ready to eat and tasty.
Be aware that this shortens the shelf life of the gingerbread. Out in the open it will dry out and keep for months. If you forget it in the tin box both the apple and the gingerbread will go moldy after after a week or two.

When people talk about keeping food in closed packaging to “maintain freshness”, they are specifically referring to keeping oxygen out, and (sometimes) keeping water in. Anything that lets water in is going to let oxygen in as well, so you’re basically going to have to pick your demise.
Buuut, if you wanted, you could simply store the gingerbread in a gas-tight container with some soaking wet paper towels to keep the humidity up. That’s probably the best approach if you’re specifically looking for water to be absorbed.
A lower-humidity version of this (75% RH instead of 100%) is soaking the paper towel in a saturated salt solution.

I gave you a vote because I appreciate an attempt, but this seems like speculation, not a known answer. Does anybody commonly store backed goods in air-tight containers with a wet paper towel (regardless of saline solution?

Sure, I have a few times. I use the saline approach in my fermentation chamber for koji. As Joe mentioned, sliced apples can also be used. Is there something in particular that makes you believe this is just speculation?
